# Cleaning small differences in hashtags with string distance method

Tags: r, text-mining

I am working on hashtags. A small number of differences exist beetween strings.Some hashtags are verbs or names or are plural or singular... 
They all have the same meaning. In the case of a statistical study I have to count the "sorties" "sorties" "sorties"...I am trying to keep only I declination of each word.

For examples:
sortir (going out):
sortir (verb), sortie (name, singular) , sorties (name, plural):

Japon (english)
Japan (French)

Here's my data:

```
data <- as.character (c("Brest", "Nantes", "sortir", "sortir", "sortie", "sorties", "icones", "icones", "icone", "Icone", "japan", "japon"))
```

print data)

My results:

```
"Brest"  
"Nantes"
"sortir" 
"sortir"
"sortie"
"sorties"
"icones" 
"icones"
"icone"
"Icone" 
"japan" 
"japon"
```

What I want: 
I want to clean my data ad keepin only one word for each declination of hashtags.

```
"Brest"  
"Nantes"
"sortir" 
"sortir"
"sortir"
"sortir"
"icones" 
"icones"
"icones"
"icones" 
"japan" 
"japan"
```

What I did:

```
# convert text to lower cases:
library (stringr)
data_lowercase <- tolower(data)
print (data_lowercase)

# converting to data frame object
data_lowercase_df <- as.data.frame(data_lowercase)
data_lowercase_df

# calculating string distance with levenshtein method
library (stringdist)
distance <- stringdistmatrix(data_lowercase ,
                         useNames="strings",
                         method="lv")
# Creating a matrix
distance2 <-  as.matrix(distance)
distance2

# Converting to a data.frame object 
library(reshape2)
distance_df <- unique(melt(distance2))
print (distance_df)

#Keeping text distance <3for "good" matches.
library (dplyr)
distance_df_2 <- distance_df %>%
filter (value>=0 & value<3)
print (distance_df_2)
```

Comment: I don't see a question.

Comment: "What I want" section. I am looking for help for asking a question that describe my cleaning goal.

Comment: How do we know which to keep between , say, .. `sortir`, `sorties` and `sortie` ?

Comment: We can keep any of these. They are equivalent in reallity.

Comment: Go lookup the `tm` package and learn some terminology to use in text analysis. I cannot see why sortie/sorties ( both nouns) should be mapped to sortir(a verb)

Comment: These words are used in hashtags . They all have the same meaning. In the case of a statistical study I have to count out the "sorties" "sorties" "sorties"...I am trying to keep only I declination of each word.

Comment: Maybe work with text similarities, stringdist, soundex?

Comment: I think soundex is not working with french...

Comment: I'd suggest using a [database of conjugations](http://enotero.pagesperso-orange.fr/bas_conj.htm) and grabbing the past participle. Then add letters according to regex rules. Add 'é/ée/és/ées' to every -er verb and 'e/s/es' to the rest.

Comment: Tank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Stemming and unstemming maybe? `stems <- SnowballC::wordStem(data, language = "french");tm::stemCompletion(stems, data)`?

Comment: Thank for your help, stemming reduce my corpus but is not really what I need. I think lemmatization will be a good method (tm package?)